# autorun a linux program on startup from a non-root user in centOS 6 64bit

Tags: linux, centos, services, chkconfig

I have a software that needs to be run via specific user "non-root" hence its home directory is `/home/non-root/`, *I have to emphasize that the program must not be run via root and must only run after mysql has started running*

And it has a software that needs to run via command: `./athena-start start`. I am not really familiar with unix system, I tried googling for any tutorial, but I had no luck finding a guide that teaches how to auto-run via non-root and on centos, I found [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206246/units-from-non-root-user-for-commands-start-stop-enable-disable), but seems like it is only for Fedora.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few approaches to this. An init script, using crontab and various others. The simplest one, in my humble opinion, is to use `@reboot` tag in crontab of the user who should be running `athena-start start` command.

The `@reboot` tag runs command exactly once after your computer boots. Use `crontab -e -u <yourusername>` to put what follows into crontab of the user of your choice. What follows is what you should put into the crontab.

```
@reboot while [ "x`ps -ef|awk '$8 ~ /[:print:]*mysqld[:mysqld:]*/ { print $2 }'|wc -l`" == "x0" ]; do sleep 10 ; done && cd /your/directory && ./your_command
```

It might be a good idea to write that into a script and place somewhere, instead of using a horrible one-liner in your crontab. The idea behind all that is: we check the process table every 10 seconds and if we find a match, ie. there is a mysqld process (or something closely resembling it), we exit the loop, change to the directory where the precious command to be run is and then run the command in the end.

Another option would be to write an init script which starts after MySQL daemon, but an example for that would require contents of the line beginning with `# chkconfig` of your MySQL init script.

Comment: Hello! Thanks, my server did not have crontab installed, so I installed using `yum install cronie` is it right? But after running `crontab -e <yourusername>` via root user I got this error: `crontab: usage error: no arguments permitted after this option`. Actually, I learned that I do not need to know if mysql is running already, because the software seems to run every 15secs until it can connect to Mysql, so I do not think I still need "script" match function? I really appreciate this.

Comment: The command example I gave was simply incorrect. I simply did not include `-u` command line switch which is needed when editing another user's crontab. Answer has been edited to include a correct example.

Comment: Tried it and I think it is working. Man! Thank you very much, how can I confirm that your reply is the answer?